# How to compile a complete list of MySQL "Words"

Tags: mysql, syntax

Really getting into MySQL and one thought I've had on mastering one aspect of it is to gather a complete listing of MySQL words. One example of this might be the [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) list, though it appears that's not a complete list; example: CONCAT, CRC32, etc.

Bizarre as it may seem, I was thinking that such a list might exist, or that there might even be a query that would yield it, and/or a way to extract it from the source code of MySQL.

Comment: Well, depends on your definition of "reserved words". technically speaking, CONCAT and CRC32 are [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html). Then, atop that, are [data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html).

Comment: @Brad Christie: My definition of a MySQL word is any string of letters that entered via the MySQL command or system command (given the right context) would have meaning to MySQL. The reference to "reserved words" was just that, a reference to it being a example of just a list of words that have meaning to MySQL; it's not complete, and I'm looking a complete list. Clearly I'm aware of the online manual, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a list of MySQL words in one place. Thanks for commenting! If you have any additional questions, just let me know.

Comment: In a sane database system, I'm sure there would be a command for that. In MySQL, not so much :)

Comment: @mikl: I agree... :-) ...though I do not know of any system that has a command that outputs a context-free listing of strings that in context it would recognize. Do you know of any?

Comment: Well, in PostgreSQL's shell, you can access lists with commands like `\dT` for data types, `\do` for operators, etc. All user defined objects can be listed, and combined with the known list of built-ins, I think it should be reasonably simple to cobble something together. Not that it would help one bit with MySQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a non-scientific method, but what I would do is:

- extract all strings from Native_func_registry func_array. Lookup for it  sql/item_create.cc , e.g in

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/item_create.cc

Those should cover builtin functions.

- extract strings from 'symbols' and 'functions' in lexer :

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/lex.h

- extract symbols from bison input http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/sql_yacc.yy  from lines

  %token SOMETOKEN

except when tokens have _SYM suffix (they are covered by sql/lex.h)

Combine all of those, and the resulting set might come near :)

Comment: vaintroub: Super, thanks - plus finally a reason to look at the source... :-) ...cheers!!